# Which environment use for writing HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, css, ide

I'm intermediate java programer. I have good knowledge on java fundamentals and programming in general. So i don't have problems get used to different IDEs and start with new languages. I want tu dive deeper in java front end development. I have HTML basics so i know that you should(can) start writing HTML+CSS+JS in ordinary windows notepad. But i did it that way some time ago so first i need to refresh my knowledge and after that gain new information.

**So my question is is it still valid approach to use notepad or should i immediately start coding in some more specialized software such as Dreamweaver**

Comment: *"more specialized software such as Dreamweaver"* Hehehe, anything but Dreamweaver.

Comment: Well im a beginner with this one so i am asking more experienced users :) Dreamweaver was first software that came into my mind. Also i dont see why this question is down voted . I didnt find any duplicate and i think it can be usefull also for other folks here new to front end

Comment: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a **tool**, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_ - SO "off-topic" flagging reason

Comment: I see. Still I find that question usefull even if it cots me some rep. After all SO is about good advices not rep :)

Comment: SO isn't about "What IDE should I use" questions, either. If it were, there wouldn't be a option to mark them off-topic for that exact reason I posted..

Comment: IDE choice is purely down to personal preference and what you feel comfortable coding in, it's a debate that can go on forever and a day. I say jump on google, have a plod around, and see what will work best for you. Some guys will say brackets, some will say sublime some will say notepad (if you want to be hard on yourself), the list goes on and on and on.

Comment: I didnt mean to start debate such as what is better eclipse/Netbeans or Linux/Win. Just wanted some ideas but now i see why that downvote occured

Answer (score 2):

I never would code in notepad. You have no file-encoding and no syntax-highlighting. You cant see simple mistakes.

A good start for every language is Notepad++ when you are on windows. At Linux I use Geany.

When it comes to bigger application with php I recommend phpStorm

Answer (score 1):

For just a simple and small project or refreshing your skills, notepad++ is absolutely okay. To do a little bit more I would use PhpStorm from JetBrains, which got excellent support for HTML, JS, CSS, PHP and also some JS-Frameworks such as JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I use Eclipse IDE with plugins for each programming language, for example, PDT for PHP.

I recommend both for small projects, and for larger applications.

It is free.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using notepad. It does not depend on your ckills in koding, notepad just won't let you see all the syntax as it should be seen and it will be much harder to write a code. Taking in consideration how long HTML codes are.

I would personally recomend using Sublime Text 2, i've been using it since the begining. It is perfect both for beginners and experienced users featuring lots and lots of settings. It understands almost any traditional language. And it's also free :)